# xpath click fails in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, xpath, junit4, selenium-chromedriver

I tried using xpaths obtained from xPathsOnClick Chrome extension. Neither worked in Chrome

```
/html/body/div[@id='content']/section[@id='landing']/button[@class='wide'] 
//section[@id='landing']/button[@class='wide'] 

System.out.println("clicking xpath");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='landing']/button[@class='wide']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("clicking xpath again");    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='landing']/button[@class='wide']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

I then tried to generate a script by recording clicks in FireFox using Selenium IDE, which recorded this click. This works when I run the selenium script using the FireFox Driver in my JUNIT4 test, but fails when I use ChromeDriver:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.wide")).click();
```

But I need to run my test in Chrome. What could be causing my script to fail in Chrome but not in FireFox?

Here is my stack trace that is returned when this errors.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=32.0.1700.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241036,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.04 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.37.1', revision: 'a7c61cbd68657e133ae96672cf995890bad2ee42', time: '2013-10-21 09:08:07'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.local', ip: 'xxxxxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: 80610629a5bacb30e815dacc5077693a
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/0n/n2fztz7x2ssdk6fncrw2csk02pm9vz/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.AHvKDM}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=32.0.1700.102, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:396)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:431)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at com.thelathe.FactorTrack_selenium.testFactorTrack(FactorTrack_selenium.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I put a Thread.sleep(5000) immediately in front of the click method but it still errors with the same message

```
Thread.sleep(5000);          
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='landing']/button[@class='wide']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: What is the failure?  Doesn't click?  Throws an exception?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I did not include the stacktrace, here it is. I sanitized it of my computer name and ip address

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element?? It may not have loaded by the time you clicked it.

Comment: NoSuchElement suggests a couple things - The element has not loaded, or the element is in a frame or iframe.  As Husam said, putting a wait around the element may help.

Comment: For wait I use Thread.sleep(5000) before the click method but it still causes the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the elements were behind an iFrame. Its not necessary for me to test it through the iFrame so I was able to resolve my issue.